# how to print missing line in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am searching a particular line in a file.
If my required line is not present i want to print that line is missing in the file.
For example my file contains below lines:

```
 list 0
 list 7
 list 2
 list 5
```

Here is the I have written so far :

```
fo=open(filename,"r")
for i in range(0,6):
    str="list"+str(i)
    for line in fo.readlines():
        if not str in line:
            print "%s%s" %(str,"is missing in file"
```

please anyone help me

Comment: you cannot concat a list and a string and using `str` as a variable name is a very bad idea, which line are you checking to see if it is missing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: He's not concatenating a list, he's concatenating whatever is in the name `list`, which might be the string `'list '` (or it might be the builtin type, if he hasn't defined anything…). Which just makes it an even better illustration of your point that naming variables `list` and `str` is a bad idea. :)

Comment: Additionally, don't use `.readlines()` where you did... just iterate over the file object. Calling `.readlines()` first requires the whole file to be read into a list for no good reason.

Comment: @Wooble: But he has to iterate the file 7 times, so in that case, reopening the file 7 times may be a lot worse than using `readlines`. It depends on the size of the file. (Although I'd still write it as `list(fo)` just to make it clear that I'm _intentionally_ making a persistent list, not just doing it by accident…)

Comment: @abarnert: well, you just pointed out another huge bug in his program. After the first time through the loop, the .readlines() will return an empty list. He's not making a persistent list by accident or otherwise.

Comment: @Wooble: Yes, I already pointed that out in my answer. There are multiple huge bugs in this code…

Comment: @all: list is a string. Now i corrected the post

Comment: @gokul: Do you realize that `"list"+str(0)` is going to be `"list0"`, which is not the same string as `"list 0"`, so you'll never find anything?

Comment: I think this question should not be downvoted, people could learn a whole lot from this question and the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `list+str(i)` isn't going to work, unless you happen to have defined `list = 'list '` somewhere earlier.

The second problem is that by naming your variable `str`, you're hiding the function `str`, which means you can't call that function the next time through the loop.

The third problem is that you only open the file once, but you call `readlines()` on it 7 times. After the first time, there are no more lines to read, so you'll get an empty list back. Just call it once, outside the loop, and store the value: `lines = fo.readlines()`. Or, alternatively, reopen the file each time through the loop, instead of just once.

The third problem is that you're going to print the output once for every line that doesn't, instead of just one if *any* line doesn't match. This one is the only part that's tricky, so I'll come back to it.

The fourth problem is that your `print` statement is missing a `)`.

Finally, you've tagged your question with both python-2.7 and python-3.x. I'll assume you weren't just trying to throw on every tag in the world in hopes that would get more viewers, and actually want your code to run under both 2.7 and 3.3. In that case, you can't use `print` as a statement; you have to use it as a function.

So, how do you say "if the string is not in any of the lines"? The easy way is with the `any` function:

```
if not any(s in line for line in lines):
```

If you can't understand that, you can get the same effect by writing out the loop explicitly, something like this:

```
found = False
for line in lines:
    if s in line:
        found = True
        break
if not found:
```

There are a lot of other problems that you *should* fix (e.g., close the file—ideally by using a `with` statement; avoid `readlines` when possible; etc.), but no more that you *need* to fix. So, here's a minimally-edited working version:

```
fo=open(filename,"r")
lines = fo.readlines()
for i in range(0,6):
    s='list '+str(i)
    if not any(s in line for line in lines):
        print("%s%s" %(s,"is missing in file"))
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It's already there. See the last paragraph.

Comment: Ah ok, I see it now, better to  use `print "%s is missing in file" % (s)` or `print "{} is missing in file".format(s)` also?

Comment: I think the {}+format is preferred in the python docs, but people have been using '%' for a long time :)

Comment: @MattWarren: I think Padraic was more suggesting moving the literal part into the format string instead of passing it to `%s` than changing from `%`-formatting to `{}`-formatting. And he's right, that's another thing that isn't exactly wrong but could be improved.

Comment: @MattWarren: As for which one is "preferred," it deliberately never says that anywhere. The original proposal was going to deprecate `%` and remove it in 3.x; then they were going to deprecate it but not remove it until some later date; then they decided not to deprecate it but to warn that `{}` was preferred and should be used in new code; finally there was just a [note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) explaining that `%` is quirky and less extensible. (Sometimes `%` really is better, and often they're both equally fine.)

Answer (score 0):

You should never name a variable `str` as `str` is a builtin type in Python.  Also, you were attempting to concatenate `list`, a function and a type, and a string.  Instead you want to concatenate the string `'list '` with the string representation of the numbers.  You don't need to call `readlines()` where you did.  Instead, read the file into a list early and iterate over that list.

```
fo=open(filename,"r").readlines()
for i in range(0,6):
    s = 'list ' + str(i)
    foundline = False
    for line in fo:
        if s in line:
            foundline = True
            break
    if not foundline: 
        print "%s%s" % (s,"is missing in file")
```

Comment: No, this won't work; you open the file, iterate over all the lines with i=0, then iterate all the lines—of which there are now none—with i=1, and so one. You either need to read the lines into a list (as the OP did), re-open and re-read the file each time, or use something like `linecache`. (Also, `fo()` is going to raise, because a file isn't callable, but that's an obvious typo.)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename,'r') as infile:
  inlines=infile.readlines()

for term in xrange(0,10):
  line='list %d\n' % term
  if line not in inlines:
    print line,'is not in the file'
```

//nb, this matches the entire search string to the input line. I assume you mean this rather than to look for the search term inside the  input line, becuase  searching for 'line 1'  inside the line would match against 'line 1', 'line 10', 'line 1000' etc..

Comment: Why are you replacing his `range(0, 6)` with `xrange(0, 10)`? (I'm asking about both the `6` to `10` change and the `range` to `xrange` change; for the latter, you think creating a list of 6 items is going to be a performance problem?)

Comment: sorry ur script is showing the below output:list 0 is not in the file
list 1 is not in the file
list 2 is not in the file
list 3 is not in the file
list 4 is not in the file
list 6 is not in the file
list 7 is not in the file
list 8 is not in the file
list 9 is not in the file

Comment: xrange, just a habit. 6 to 10, no real reason other than to show the idea.  And sorry.. yes :) I missed a \n off the search string I believe, corrrected it now.  The '\n' is required because reading the lines from the file will include the line endings.

Comment: - also this is written to match the term to an entire line, not to see if the term is in the line. (looking for 'list 1' inside a line returns True for 'list 1'  'list 10'   'list 1000'  etc..